# Snap svg dynamic : wrong positioning

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

With Snap SVG I am trying to create an rect dynamically.

When I click, it should create a rect at the position of the mouse click.

it's create the rect, BUT the postion is always wrong.

Here is my script : http://jsfiddle.net/noteStylet/L2kpd6yt/

So My question is Who to create a rect at the mouse click postion and not below.

HTML :

```
<h1>Click to create </h1>

<div>
    <svg id="plan" width="900" height="500"></svg>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
var snap = Snap("#plan");
//create an image
var imagePlan =     snap.image("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Cathedral_schematic_plan_fr_vectorial.svg", 10, 10, 900, 500);

imagePlan.click(function (evt) {
    //When click, create a rect
    var rect1 = snap.rect(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, 40, 40);

});
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should use this method :

```
var transformed = pt.matrixTransform(mySvg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
var rect1 = s.rect(transformed.x, transformed.y, 40, 40);
```

instead of

```
var rect1 = snap.rect(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, 40, 40);
```

We have to use :

```
var mySvg = $("#svg1")[0];

var pt = mySvg.createSVGPoint(); // create the point;

imagePlan.click(function(evt)
    {
        pt.x = evt.x;
        pt.y = evt.y;

        // convert the mouse X and Y so that it's relative to the svg element
        var transformed = pt.matrixTransform(mySvg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
        var rect1 = s.rect(transformed.x, transformed.y, 40, 40);

    });
```

Here is the Example  : http://jsfiddle.net/noteStylet/L2kpd6yt/6/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the grid system of the svg you need to re-abjust it so that your mouse is not the (0,0) but rather the (-20,-80).
change the rect creation code to :

`var rect1 = snap.rect(evt.clientX-20, evt.clientY-80, 40, 40);`

and it should work

update:

Ok so what you need is 1.get mouse position and 2.the position of the image ( left & top values). Then subtract them from current mouse position so you can adjust the svg grid to feet your needs

```
var snap = Snap("#plan");
//create an image
var imagePlan = snap.image("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Cathedral_schematic_plan_fr_vectorial.svg", 10, 10, 900, 500);
 var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
        currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
        currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
        var image = $( "#plan" );
        var position = image.position();
 imagePlan.click(function()
        {

            //When click, create a rect
            var rect1 = snap.rect(currentMousePos.x-position.left ,currentMousePos.y-position.top, 40, 40);


        });

    });
```

Comment: Yes, it'works, but if I add another tag <h1><div><p> ... before the svg the problem is back...

Comment: so i updated my answer hope this solves your problem